# Cookie Domain Precedence?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have a few sites.  Each site is a localized version serving up content specific to the a given set of locales. There is also a World Wide or "Global" site.  I have them setup as follows:

- http://mydomain.com
- http://us.mydomain.com
- http://uk.mydomain.com
- etc...

I am trying to track activity on each application using a cookie.  The cookie name for each site is the same, and using the default settings for domain (i.e. in .net I am not specifying a value for httpCookie.Domain - I am leaving it default).

Everything works fine when I am visiting my "locale specific" sites, but once I visit the "global" site, it seems that the cookie from this site is used when I go back to visit my "locale specific" sites, rather than the cookie issued for the "locale specific" site.

Any ideas on how to get my "global" cookie from taking precedence over my "local specific" cookie on the "locale specific" sites?

Comment: Beyond the obvious idea of making your global site into "www.mydomain.com"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most browsers, setting a cookie without a ‘domain’ makes it *only* valid on the current hostname. This can't otherwise be achieved by setting any value on ‘domain’; if this behaviour is what you want you must omit the ‘domain’ parameter.

However in IE, any cookie you set without a ‘domain’ will get an implicit ‘domain’ of the current hostname. This means if you set a cookie on ‘example.com’ you can't stop it being sent to ‘sub.example.com’.

Therefore you can't have subdomains that don't share part of the security context of the parent domain. If you want to keep a subdomain apart from its parent you must (as JustLoren suggested) make the main site `www.example.com` and not just `example.com`.

When two cookies with different domains are valid, browsers will typically send them both, so you can expect a `document.cookie` like `'a=b; a=c'`. If your cookie-reading layer doesn't expect multiple cookies with the same name, one of those will disappear (you don't get any control over which).

The other approach, if you don't care about putting boundaries between the other sites and the main one, would be just to use different cookie names on the different subsites.

Comment: This was why I didn't make mine an answer.  Yours was far more informative :)

Comment: After posting, I did some reading and found similar descriptions of the issue and solutions.  What is going to work for me is the latter approach: "The other approach, if you don't care about putting boundaries between the other sites and the main one, would be just to use different cookie names on the different subsites.".  I'll just create a slightly different cookie name per site and the layer that understands how to read them, will be able to distinguish between the different names.

Answer (score 1):

bobince is right about the unusual behavior of Internet Explorer. Note that Edge works differently, more like FireFox (for this aspect).

If you don't set any cookie properties, then you will probably run into problems with the path. In your case the property `path=/` would be a good choice.

Note that there are many differences between browsers in the way they handle cookies. If you are interested, you can read [How Different Browsers Handle Cookies Differently](https://gertjans.home.xs4all.nl/javascript/cookies.html)